# Document.ready() function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

This is my ajax function

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 var num = 1;
function ajax_post(){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "javas.php";



hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send("num=" + (++num)); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

}
```

Now i have this too find the correct div/class to run the ajax function in:

```
 $('.eventcontainer.button').click(function() { 
    $.post('javas.php', function(data) {
       $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
    })
    });
```

However im not sure where to implement this in my code

Comment: Popping it in a $(document).ready(function () {} will be fine

Comment: where does the document.ready funtion come in?

Comment: If you enclose your click handler with in the document ready it will work fine . You could put the entire code it there and it would work .

Comment: It's just ensuring the DOM is loaded , you've already attached the handler to the button.

Comment: Why do you use your own ajax methods if you have jquery?

Comment: document ready is rather easy to place at... just put all your code in it except own functions... write functions outside document ready but call them inside doc ready.

Comment: I was wondering the same. Since you're using jquery, why go through the hassle of manually creating the xmlhttprequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to write your own ajax-request if you want to run your code on multiple browsers. If you have jQuery on your hand and you want a post ajax-request use the jQuery function:

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

example for document ready to use:

```
function fooBar() {
//some code
}

$(document).ready(function(){
// all your jquery in here
$('body').hide().fadeIn(2000);
// or call your own functions
fooBar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.eventcontainer.button').click(function() { 
        $.post('javas.php', function(data) {
            $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
        })
    });
})
```